# Показывать записи из БД в определенный промежуток времени

Tags: время, mysql

Всем привет.

Такой вопрос назрел.
Как лучше реализовать отображение записей из БД (MySQL) в определенный промежуток времени?

Пока вижу так, что завести две колонки tome_from и time_to и потом уже получать текущее время сервера(PHP) и делать выборку меж этими полями.

Но вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы при большом количестве данных, это все не тормозило.
 + к этому, ограничений по времени может не быть. т.е. показ будет с 0 часов и до 0 часов.

Буду благодарен за советы.

Comment: Делаете поле (поля), ответственные за время, делаете выборку по ним. No magic in here.

Comment: @Etki, это то понятно)

Временной диапазон может быть не задан. Т.е. нужно еще проверять, есть ли что-то в tome_from и time_to. А это доп. условия в запросе.

Ставить ли индексы на эти поля?

При этом записей в БД может быть и 100к и больше.

Я такое никогда не делал и боюсь, что получиться большая нагрузка. Вот и спрашиваю, как такое лучше делать.)

Comment: индексы обязательно на поля.

Comment: @drop_off, не задан - не проверяйте по этим полям, делов-то )

Comment: а что за данные? какой их характер? как часто они меняются? нужно сегодня выводить то, что было вчера + дополнять новыми? 

Может стоит продумать схему с предварительной нарезкой данных на временные блоки и хранить их отдельно в каком-нть кэше (memcache/filecache)?

Comment: @boris_U, просто вывод записей, у которых установлен показ от определенного и до определенного часа. Скажем, установили показ записи с 8 утра и до 16 вечера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ускорения выборки поля лучше проиндексировать. Как я понял у Вас там только целые числа будут в диапазоне от 0 до 23. Поэтому (сейчас меня наверное тапочками закидают) я бы тип данных поставил `TINYINT 3 UNSIGNED`. Меньше памяти займет буфер при выборке. Далее предлагают проиндексировать. Разумно. Но у этого индекса будет низкая селективность, т.к. разброс значений небольшой на 100к записей. Тем более что в некоторой части записей будет вообще 0 стоять. Но даже если проиндексировать, то стоит задаться вопросом, а не сделать ли составной индекс по двум полям (`KEY (time_from, time_to)`). Для этого нужно задаться вопросом будут ли выборки отдельно по полю time_to. Если будут и их кол-во достаточное большое, то нужно сделать 2 индекса. Составной `KEY(time_from, time_to)` и отдельно на поле `KEY(time_to)`.

Comment: Да, храню целые числа.

Выборка будет по двум полям только. Составной и сделал.

Вопрос теперь в том, как лучше сделать в запросе условие, чтобы в случае, если time_from и time_to = 0, то не фильтровать по ним.

Т.е. банальный IF что ли?
Я просто с условиями не работал и не знаю, как правильно, что делать в такой ситуации.

Comment: > если time_from и time_to = 0
Я бы просто не добавлял их в WHERE

Comment: @dimka3210, а как я узнаю до запроса, что time_from и time_to = 0?
Я вот как раз и не могу правильно условие тут составить.

Что-то типа такого пытаюсь сделать:

    $h = 20;// текущее время

в запросе

    (time_from > 0 AND '.$h.' >= time_from AND time_to > 0 AND time_to <= '.$h.') 
    OR 
    (time_from = 0 AND time_to = 0)

Comment: @drop_off, т.е. нужно одним запросом выбрать, строки которые попадают в диапазон и у которых он (диапазон) не указан?

Comment: @dimka3210, не обязательно в одном. Мне главное, чтобы запросы быстро работали.

Просто если это реально в одном, то лучше, конечно.

Вроде получилось по примеру, который выше.